# Javadoc With Ant

Tags: java, ant, javadoc

I try to generate my javadoc with ant.
My javadoc.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<project default="main" basedir=".">
 <target name="main" >
    <javadoc packagenames="com.prosodie.volta.*"
           sourcepath="../src"
           defaultexcludes="yes"
           destdir="docs/api"
           author="true"
           version="true"
           use="true"
           windowtitle="Test API">
    </javadoc>
  </target>
</project>
```

When i run it i get a

> *...\workspace\volta2\volta-rest-webservices\ant\javadoc.xml:14: No source files and no packages have been specified.*<

I don't understand why, as i specified the src dir and packages..
My structure :

```
project

  ant
    javadoc.xml
  src
    main
      java
        com
          prosodie
            volta
              ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `sourcepath` from:

```
 sourcepath="../src"
```

To

```
sourcepath="../src/main/java"
```

As your package is within that particular folder and not in src.